# Differences between OLAP and OLTP databases

Tags: sql, database

What are the key differences between OLAP and OLTP databases.
Specifically in terms of implementation (rather than use cases).

OLAP is of course primarily used for reporting while OLTP is used for handling transactions.

I understand that OLAP databases are optimized for read over write, and that OLAP databases contain more denormalised data.

What other characteristics set the two apart?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OLTP:

- As the name suggest "Online Transaction Processing", this is used for more transaction needs like  "INSERT/SELECT/UPDATE/DELETE".
- Low Response Time.
- There are the original source of data.
- Usually data is stored in 3NF form.
- ACID properties are necessarily followed.

OLAP:

- As the name suggest "Online Analytical Platform", used for analytical queries and in general are used for complex analytical queries and drawing inferences.
- Periodic batch processing jobs are run here.
- Typically de-normalized with fewer tables; use of star and/or snowflake schemas.
- NOT necessarily follows ACID properties.

Comment: What's the reasoning behind the need for ACID between the two?

Answer (score 1):

There are many difference. You may find tons of answers by googling this question. But some of the characteristics which are derived from practical implementation from my own experiences are:

OLTP is business domain specific system designed to perform specific tasks for example an eCommerce website having a database for handling online order while another OLTP database  is being used for back end operation for order processing another OLTP database is for logistics etc. Whereas OLAP systems are designed to look at the information at whole business level by sourcing data from many heterogeneous system.

If I simplified the above example then OLTP is small units of Business Processing system while OLAP system is a large unit of Business Information.

You can refer this [link](http://datawarehouse4u.info/OLTP-vs-OLAP.html) for more clarification.